# How to create a multiple range sliders control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider

I'm working on a user control to create and manipulate multiple time slots on the timeline. On the image below is an example of one row (representing a task) with three time slots:

[image: Time slots]

The time slots will be bepossible to add, remove and manipulate - resize and move (slide) with mouse. Resizing will be done with dragging the edges/thumbs of time slot. A slot is resizable only if there are days that are not taken by another slot (no slot overlapping will be possible).

There will be multiple rows with the slots representing other tasks.

I'm able to create one slot as a range slider (with ticks as days) however I do not know if it's possible to create a collection of range sliders to represent multiple slots or I should choose an another approach to design such a control.

Thanks for any ideas how to design such a control.

Comment: This is a really broad question amigo. However if it's literally just a visualization just slap a colored rectangle in there that will stretch the size of it's parent. Except without knowing more about the overall layout, more details of the overall UX, etc, etc, etc. You're fishing for broad opinions.

Comment: @ChrisW. Hey Chris, thanks for the remarks. I've tried to update my question and provide more details. Hope it's less broad.

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate for advice on how to extend the basic `Slider` control to have more than one thumb (or rather, how to layer multiple `Slider` controls so that visually they appear as one). If you have trouble implementing your multi-slider control and can provide a _specific_ question, please post a new question, including a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, along with a precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.